# Finding all real solutions for the exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all real numbers $x$ such that $2^x + 3^x - 4^x + 6^x - 9^x =1$.

Comment: By inspection, $1+1-1+1-1=1$ so $\underline{~~~~~}$ is a solution.  Then, one can make an argument that it is furthermore a maximum of $f(x)=2^x+3^x-4^x+6^x-9^x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: put $u = 2^x, v = 3^x$, and turn it into a quadratic equation:
$u+v - u^2+uv-v^2 - 1 = 0 \implies -u^2+(1+v)u + v-v^2-1 = 0 \implies \triangle = -3(v-1)^2 \le 0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: $2^x + 3^x - 4^x + 6^x - 9^x =1$

$2^x + 3^x - 2^{2x} + 2^x\cdot 3^x - 3^{2x} =1$

Let $2^x=a;\;3^x=b$

$b^2-(a+1) b+a^2-a+1=0$

Solving wrt $b$

$b= \dfrac{1}{2} \left(a+1\pm\sqrt{3} \sqrt{-(a-1)^2}\right)$

as the discriminant is $\Delta=-(a-1)^2\leq 0\quad \forall a\in\mathbb{R} $

the only possibility is that $\Delta=0\to a=1$

which means $2^x=1\to x=0$

Furthermore for $a=1$ we have $b=1$ which means $3^x=1\to x=0$

So the only solution to this equation is $x=0$

hope this helps